# Multi-degree Forced spring-mass system with damper energy conservation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, matlab

Edit: It was kindly pointed out to me in the comments that because of the MATLAB code I should post in [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) as this is a mathematics-oriented forum. However I want to clarify that there is no problem with the code, its just the theory behind it that I am not comprehending. The code is there to help with visualisng the problem and getting familiar with the details.

**The Problem:**

Having writen a MATLAB code to solve a 3 Degree of freedom, forced, spring-mass system with a damper, I try to evaluate the energy balance for every time $t$ of the solution. I am lead to believe from my results that I have done this correctly as the energy balance is virtually $0$ with an input force phase angle of $\phi=[120^{\circ}, 240^{\circ}, 360^{\circ}]^T$. However, by changing the input force phase angles to something arbitraty such as $\phi=[52^{\circ}, 114^{\circ}, 171^{\circ}]^T$, the energy balance does not hold anymore which shouldn't be the case obviously.

**Some Context:**

The system is modelled as shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35jiY.png) image, with the following equation:

$\mathbf{M\ddot{x} + C\dot{x} + Kx = F(t)}$

Wehere $\mathbf{F(t)}$ is a simple sinusoidal response. Naturally, the energy in the system is as follows:

$\begin{align}
PE & = \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{ x(t)^T K x(t)} && \,\text{i.e. the Potential Energy}\\
KE & = \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{ \dot{x}(t)^T M \dot{x}(t)} &&  \,\text{i.e. the Kinetic Energy} \\
DE & = \int^t_0 \mathbf{\dot{x}(t)^T C \dot{x}(t)}dt &&  \,\text{i.e. the Dissipated Energy} \\
EE & = \int^t_0 \mathbf{\dot{x}(t)F(t)}dt &&  \,\text{i.e. the Excitation Force Energy} \\
\end{align}$

Hence, based on the above, I would assume that the energy balance at any point $t$ would be:

$KE+PE+DE = EE + c$

where $c$ is a constant depending on the energy present from the intial conditions of the system.

Apparently, there seems that there must be a flaw in my logic above, as by running the code attached, by changing the phase angle of the excitation force $\phi$ (line 24) the above does not hold true anymore.

Thanks for your help in advance,

KMT.

P.S.

**The Code**

```
clear ; clc

% User Inputs

% Coefficients
m = 3 ;         % Mass, kg
k = 20 ;        % Spring constant, N/m
c = 2 ;         % Damper constant, Ns/m
f0= 10 ;        % Excitation force amplitude, N
f = 0.5;        % Excitation force frequency, Hz

% Degrees of freedom
N = 3 ;

% Solver inputs
tmax = 30 ;     % Maximum solution time
vi = 0 ;        % Initial velocity of 1st DoF

% Matrices
M = diag(repmat(m, 1, N)) ;
K = tridiag(repmat(k, 1, N+1)) ;
C = tridiag(repmat(c, 1, N+1)) ;
F = diag(repmat(f0, 1, N)) ; 
Phi = linspace(2*pi/N,2*pi,N)' ; % <-- Change to [1 2 3]'

% ODE Solution
tspan = [0 tmax] ;
y0 = [zeros(1, N) vi zeros(1, N-1)] ;

[t, y] = ode45(@(t, y) odefcn(t, y, M, K, C, F, Phi, f, N), tspan, y0) ;

[Ec, En, Ee] = energy(t, y, M, K, C, F, Phi, f, N) ;

% Plotting
fig = figure;
gcf = fig ;
fig.Color = 'w' ;
fig.Position = [400 200 900 500] ;

subplot(2, 1, 1)
    yyaxis right
    plot(t, y(:,1:N))
    ylabel('Displacement (m)') ;

yyaxis left
    plot(t, y(:,N+1:2*N))
    ylabel('Velocity (m/s)') ; xlabel('Time (s)') 
    legend(sprintfc('Mass %d',1:N),'Location','Northoutside','Orientation','Horizontal')
    grid on

subplot(2, 1, 2)
    yyaxis right
    plot(t, [Ec En Ee])
    ylabel('Energy (J)') ;

    yyaxis left
    plot(t, sum([Ec En -Ee], 2))
    legend('Total Energy', 'Kinetic + Potential Energy', 'Dissipated Energy','Input Energy','Location','Northoutside','Orientation','Horizontal') 
    ylabel('Energy (J)') ;  xlabel('Time (s)')
    grid on

% Energy function
function [Ec, En, Ee] = energy(t, ymat, M, K, C, F, Phi, f, N) 

% Indexes
i = N ; 
j = N+1 ; 
k = 2*N ; 

% Extract Variables
y  = ymat(:, 1:i)' ;
dy = ymat(:, j:k)' ;

% Energy/Power Equations
KE = 0.5 * dy' * M * dy ;                       % Kinetic energy
PE = 0.5 * y' * K * y ;                         % Potential energy
DP = dy' * C * dy ;                             % Dissipated power
EP = abs(dy' * F*sin(2*pi*f*t' - Phi)) ;        % Excitation power

Ec = diag(KE + PE) ;                            % Sum of potential & kinetic energy
En = cumtrapz(t,diag(DP)) ;                     % Integrated dissipated power over time
Ee = cumtrapz(t,diag(EP)) ;                     % Integrated excitation power

end

% ODE function
function dydt = odefcn(t, y, M, K, C, F, Phi, f, N)

% Indexes
i = N ;
j = N+1 ;
k = 2*N ;

% Preallocate
dydt = zeros(k, 1) ;

% Equation
dydt(1:i) = y(j:k) ;
dydt(j:k) = M \ (-C*y(j:k) -  K*y(1:i) + F*sin(2*pi*f*t - Phi)) ;

end

% Tri-diagonal matrix function
function X = tridiag(x_c)

 x(:,:,1) = diag(x_c(1:end-1)) ;
 x(:,:,2) = diag(x_c(2:end)) ;
 x(:,:,3) = diag(-x_c(2:end-1), -1);
 x(:,:,4) = diag(-x_c(2:end-1), 1) ;

 X = sum(x,3) ;

end
```

Comment: This might be better suited for Super User. https://superuser.com

Comment: Is this because it includes MATLAB code?

Comment: Yes. SuperUser has a dedicated MatLab tag, and you are more likely to get an answer there. Math Stack Exchange site is geared towards mathematics, and less towards code or programming.

Comment: Apologies, I did not clarify. There is no problem with the code, its just there to help visualise the problem and get familiar with the details. Its the theory behind it that's the problem on how I apply the energy conservation.

Comment: On this platform you also have the relevant [physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com) and [scientific computing](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com) fora.